# Object.keys(arr).reduce() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object

I am creating an object from an array like so

```
var val = $(this).val();
 var type = " " + $("#backing").val() + " ";
      var arr = $.extend({}, comb_arr[type]);
```

The result

```
var arr = {"1-4  ": "$10.10 ", "5-9  ": "$8.34 ", "10-24  ": "$7.71 ", "25-49  ": "$7.21 "}
```

When I run the below code through the output is undefined

```
var price = Object.keys(arr).reduce((a, c) => {
     var s = c.trim();
     if(/\d+\-\d+/.test(s)){
        var range = s.split("-");
        if(val >= parseInt(range[0]) && val <= parseInt(range[1])){
            a = comb_arr[c];
        }
     }else{
        s = s.replace(/\D/g, "");
        if(val >= s){
            a = comb_arr[c];
        }
     }
     return a;
  },0);
```

All ideas are welcome!

Comment: Can you give the array that you start with?

Comment: Are you sure you want `comb_arr[c]`, not `arr[c]` (i.e. `comb_arr[type][c]`)?

Comment: may I know what's `val`?

Comment: @Bergi You were right! That solved my problem, please post as an answer so I can give credit where it is due!

Comment: Using `reduce` here looks wrong. It seems like you want the value of the last property whose name fulfills a certain condition? But objects are unordered, so there is no "last".